# Как использовать измененную переменную в JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Как я могу использовать измененную функцией переменную в другой функции

Вот код (Функция fnk активируется в другом html)

```js
var inform = 0;

function fnk(){
 if (inf.checked) {
inform = (parseFloat(inf.value)).toFixed(0);
}


function onclickButton(){
  document.getElementById('qw').innerHTML = parseFloat(inform);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body onload="onclickButton()"> 
  <output id="qw"></output>
</body>
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
</head>

<span id="tool"><input type="checkbox" id="inf" name="inf"  value=2  onclick="fnk()"/>
        <label for="inf"><span></span>Информатика</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Подключи этот `js` файл в том самом `html` и используй ее,  как хочешь

Comment: С этим небольшая проблема. В первой функции есть условие которое связано с чекбоксами из другого HTML и из за этого он выдает ошибку когда выполняется на втором HTML

Comment: приведите весь код.

Comment: Я исправил приведенный код.

Comment: Ищите "Передача данных между страницами".

Comment: А, то есть речь прям про передачу между страницами, а не переиспользование ... ну тогда localStorage/Cookie/get/hash/...